# Npm run dev dosn't work

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm-install

Hey I'm a noob in web dev and trying to do things with **Laravel** and **Phaser**.
I'm running on Ubuntu Mint 18.1 Cinnamon(3.2.7) 64-bit
I'm always lost as hell with all the dependencies ^^"
the npm run dev give me this error

npm-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/guigeek/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/guigeek/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev' ]
2 info using npm@2.14.2
3 info using node@v4.0.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info predev @
6 info dev @
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info @ Failed to exec dev script
9 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
9 verbose stack Exit status 1
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/guigeek/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:214:16)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/guigeek/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:817:16)
9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
10 verbose pkgid @
11 verbose cwd /home/guigeek/Dev/rf
12 error Linux 4.4.0-65-generic
13 error argv "/home/guigeek/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/bin/node" "/home/guigeek/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
14 error node v4.0.0
15 error npm  v2.14.2
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error @ dev: `node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
17 error Exit status 1
18 error Failed at the @ dev script 'node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the  package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
18 error You can get their info via:
18 error     npm owner ls
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --watch-poll --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "hot": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^0.8.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Looks like you have a package.json based on the Laravel 5.4.15 template site. 5.4.16 changed stuff involving the cross-env stuff. I would also look into updating nodejs/npm versions. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.4.16/package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the node version thanks ! 
i used NVM to update node ( https://github.com/creationix/nvm ) and took it to node v7.9.0

Comment: I had the same problem, just with Sass.  For some reason Ubuntu 16.04 only comes with nodeJS v4x in their repo, so I had to do a complete uninstall of node/npm, add new PPA and then reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

you must try this

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```